# Set a main-menu item as active with custom code

Tags: 7, routes, hooks

I want to set a menu item of the main menu as active (class="active").

I'm specifically looking for a hook or function, not a contrib module.

I have seen recommendations for [Context](http://drupal.org/project/context), and I have looked in the module code, but it uses hooks which I cannot find on the [API-Site](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--module.inc/group/hooks/7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is this:

```
function mymodule_init() {
    $link=menu_link_load(346);
    $link["options"]["attributes"]["class"]="active";
    menu_link_save($link);
}
```

The id 346 is the `mlid` no idea what this mean but I got this id with this little dump:

```
echo('<pre>');
dump(menu_tree_all_data('main-menu'));
echo('</pre>');
```

Comment: Surely your solution will give the item with `mlid` (Menu Link Identifier for your reference) 346 the "active" class regardless of what is ACTUALLY the active link?  Is this your intended behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

If you simply want to add the 'active' class to a menu item you could do it in the code before printing the menu.
If you want the menu item to also act like an active item you could use [menu_tree_set_path()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_tree_set_path/7) that was supposedly added in Drupal 7.9.

In earlier versions and Drupal 6 I used this:

```
function mymodule_init() {
  $item = menu_get_item($_GET['q']);
  $item['href'] = 'node/1';
  menu_set_item(NULL, $item);
}
```

However both options just add the 'active-trail' (not 'active') class(es), but that should suffice in most cases.

Comment: This seems not to work. In the `navigation` menu the tree is expanded, but the entry in the `main-menu` is not *active*.

Comment: If you mean 'active' class then yes that one doesn't get added with this code, but it gets 'active-trail' that should be helpful. If you mean something else then I'd need a bit more information of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I have two taxonomies which splits the page in two parts. With seo stuff I managed that the two taxonomies have their own path e.g. example.com/tag1 and example.com/tag2 which is linked in the main-menu in the header. A example for content which is in the taxonomy tag1 is aviable at example.com/tag1/welcome. Now I want that the link in the main menu in the head is still active.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`menu_set_active_trail`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_set_active_trail/7) to set which menu should be rendered as active.

Another way is to mess with `$_GET['q']`, but you really want to avoid that if at all possible, since it can lead to some strange bugs.

Comment: Could you add a small example for `menu_set_active_trail`?

Comment: @rekire look at [`book_build_active_trail`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--book--book.module/function/book_build_active_trail/6) for inspiration (D6);

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `hook_translated_menu_link_alter()`

```
/**
 * Implements hook_translated_menu_link_alter()
 */
function Module_translated_menu_link_alter(&$item, $map) {

    if ($item['menu_name'] == 'menu-name') {

        //check first two arg from url
        $path = arg(0)."/".arg(1);

        //add class active-trail if path match
        if (strpos($item['link_path'], $path) !== false) {
            $item['in_active_trail'] = true;

        }

    }
}
```